# Export PowerPoint shape with real size

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I need to export shape selected in PowerPoint as png image with real shape size. I use this code for export:

```
var args = new object[] { filePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG, 0, 0, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpExportMode.ppRelativeToSlide };
objectShape.GetType().InvokeMember("Export", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objectShape, args); // Export to file on disk
```

On disk I have image with incorrect proportions and Height/Width. I've tried different values of PpExportMode enumeration parameter and just in case I changed the zoom in PP to 100%. But I have no correct results. For rectangle-based shapes it works correctly. But for example for stars or callout shapes real size doesn't equal to the shape Height/Width properties. It happens because of little tongue at the bottom of shape.

[image]

Does anybody know how to export these shapes correctly?

Comment: Where did you find this funky method: `objectShape.GetType().InvokeMember("Export",`? The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.export.aspx) says to use `Shape.Export(PathName, Filter, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight, ExportMode)`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Jeremy - My Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape have no Export method. So I've found this article [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/officegeneral/thread/e943abe2-f7f8-4b04-afc4-95ed45c4e621)

Comment: John - Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 1):

Check the shape's .Adjustments.Count property.

```
If Adjustments.Count > 0 Then
For x = 1 to Adjustments.Count
  '  Store the value of Adjustments(x) somewhere
  '  so you can reset it later
  .Adjustments(x) = 0
Next
```

Now export the shape, and then reset its adjustments to the previous values.

Or just copy the shape, set its adjustments to 0, export it, then delete it.

Comment: Steve, great thanks for your answer. It gave me the search direction. I need to export shape with all adjustments so my image should look identically with original shape (with all adjustments) with 100% zoom in PP.